# How do I allow a client to connect to python server?

Tags: python, server

When I run the server, then the client, I Automatically get these messages:

**SERVER: **
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\Ryan\Desktop\testproj-server.py", line 142, in 
handleConnectedSocket()
File "C:\Users\Ryan\Desktop\testproj-server.py", line 58, in handleConnectedSocket
rcvdStr = rcvdStr + fd.recv(1024)
TypeError: can only concatenate str (not "bytes") to str

**CLIENT: **
ERROR: Cannot connect to chat server [WinError 10056] A connect request was made on an already connected socket
Exiting... Goodbye! *

This is my code:

**SERVER CODE:**

```
import socket
import select


def runSelect():
    selectUnsuccessful = True

    while selectUnsuccessful:
        try:
            readyRecvList, readySendList, readyErrList = select.select(recvList, sendList, [])
            selectUnsuccessful = False
        except select.error:
            for fd in recvList:
                try:
                    tempRecvList, tempSendList, tempErrList = select.select([fd], [], [], 0)
                except select.error:
                    if fd == serverSocket:
                        fd.close()
                        exit(1)
                    else:
                        if fd in recvList:
                            recvList.remove(fd)
                            fd.close()

    return readyRecvList, readySendList


def handleListeningSocket():
    try:
        newConnectionSocket, addr = serverSocket.accept()
    except socket.error as err:
        print("\nERROR: Something went wrong in the accept() function call:", err)
        exit(1)

    try:
        recvList.append(newConnectionSocket)
        sendList.append(newConnectionSocket)
        print("INFO: Connecting socket created between %s and %s" %
              (newConnectionSocket.getsockname(), newConnectionSocket.getpeername()))
        print("* Client %s is ready to chat *" % (str(newConnectionSocket.getpeername())))

    except (socket.error, socket.gaierror) as err:

        print("\nERROR: Something went wrong with the new connection socket:", err)
        if newConnectionSocket in recvList:
            recvList.remove(newConnectionSocket)
            sendList.remove(newConnectionSocket)
            newConnectionSocket.close()


def handleConnectedSocket():
    try:

        recvIsComplete = False
        rcvdStr = ""

        while not recvIsComplete:
            rcvdStr = rcvdStr + fd.recv(1024)

            if fd not in sendList:
                sendList.append(fd)
                # ~ is the delimiter used to indicate message start and finish
                if rcvdStr.strip('~') != "":
                    if (rcvdStr[0] == "~") and (rcvdStr[-1] == "~"):
                        recvIsComplete = True
                        clientMessage = rcvdStr.strip('~')
                    else:  # if empty string, connection has been terminated
                        if fd in recvList:
                            recvList.remove(fd)

            if fd in sendList:
                sendList.remove(fd)
                del clientMessages[fd]  # Delete connection information
                fd.close()

            if clientMessage == "quit()":
                print ("\n* Client %s has left the chat room *\n" % (str(fd.getpeername())))

            if fd in recvList:
                recvList.remove(fd)
                fd.close()

                if fd in sendList:
                    sendList.remove(fd)
                    fd.close()

            else:
                print("\n%s: %s" % (fd.getpeername(), clientMessage))
                # add message to dictionary, pending transmission
                clientMessages[fd] = str(clientMessage)

    except socket.error as err:
        print("\nERROR: Connection to the client has abruptly ended:", err)
        if fd in recvList:
            recvList.remove(fd)

        if fd in sendList:
            sendList.remove(fd)

        fd.close()
        print("* I am ready to chat with a new client! *\n")


"""
main - Runs the Full Duplex Chat server
"""

# Global Variables
serverHost = 'localhost'
serverPort = 22222
recvList = []
sendList = []
clientMessages = {}


try:

    serverSocket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    serverSocket.setblocking(0)
    serverSocket.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1)
    serverSocket.bind((serverHost, serverPort))
    serverSocket.listen(3)

    print ("INFO: I am listening at %s" % (str(serverSocket.getsockname())))
    print ("* I am ready to chat with a new client! *\n")

except (socket.error, socket.gaierror) as err:
    print ("\nERROR: Something went wrong in creating the listening socket:", err)
    exit(1)

recvList = [serverSocket]

try:
    while True:
        serverSocket.setblocking(False)
        readyForRecv, readyForSend = runSelect()

        for fd in readyForRecv:
            if fd == serverSocket:
                handleListeningSocket()
            else:
                handleConnectedSocket()

        for fd in readyForSend:
            try:
                if fd in clientMessages.keys():  # See if connection information exists
                    broadcast = str(clientMessages[fd])  # Add message to broadcast variable

                    if broadcast:  # See if a message is actually there
                        for client in readyForSend:  # Broadcast message to every connected client
                            if broadcast != "":
                                print ("* Broadcasting message \"%s\" to %s *" % (str(broadcast), client.getpeername()))
                                client.send(str(fd.getpeername()) + ": " + str(broadcast))

                                clientMessages[fd] = ""  # Empty pending messages
#except:
    # print "\nERROR: Something awful happened while broadcasting messages"
    #break

            except socket.error as err:
                print ("\nERROR: Something awful happened with a connected socket:", err)

                if fd in recvList:
                    recvList.remove(fd)

                if fd in sendList:
                    sendList.remove(fd)

                fd.close()

except KeyboardInterrupt:
    for fd in recvList:
        fd.close()

    for fd in sendList:
        fd.close()

    print ("\nINFO: KeyboardInterrupt")
    print ("* Closing all sockets and exiting... Goodbye! *")
    exit(0)
```

**CLIENT CODE:**

```
import socket
import select
import sys


def main():

    serverHost = 'localhost'
    serverPort = 22222

    try:
        clientSocket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    except socket.error as err:
        print("ERROR: Cannot create client side socket:", err)
        exit(1)

    while True:
        try:
            clientSocket.connect((serverHost, serverPort))
        except socket.error as err:
            print("ERROR: Cannot connect to chat server", err)
            print("* Exiting... Goodbye! *")
            exit(1)
        except:
            print("ERROR: Something awful happened!")
            exit(1)
            break

    recvList = [clientSocket, sys.stdin]

    print("* You are now connected to chat server %s as %s *" %
          (clientSocket.getpeername(), clientSocket.getsockname()))

    try:
        while True:
            readyRecvList, readySendList, readyErrList = select.select(recvList, [], [])

            for fd in readyRecvList:
                if fd == sys.stdin:
                    message = sys.stdin.readline().rstrip()
                    clientSocket.sendall("~" + str(message) + "~")

                    if (message == "quit()"):
                        print("* Exiting chat room! *")
                        clientSocket.close()
                        exit(0)
                        break

                    elif fd == clientSocket:
                        clientSocket.settimeout(3)
                        try:
                            message = clientSocket.recv(2048)
                        except socket.timeout as err:
                            print("ERROR: The recv() function timed out after 3 seconds! Try again.")
                        except:
                            print("ERROR: Something awful happened!")
                    else:
                        if message == "":
                            break
                else:
                    print("%s\n" % (message))
                    clientSocket.settimeout(None)
                    break

    except select.error as err:
        for fd in recvList:
            try:
                tempRecvList, tempSendList, tempErrList = select.select([fd], [], [], 0)
            except select.error:
                if fd == clientSocket:
                    fd.close()
                    exit(1)
                else:
                    if fd in recvList:
                        recvList.remove(fd)
                        fd.close()

    except socket.error as err:
        print("ERROR: Cannot connect to chat server", err)
        print("* Exiting... Goodbye! *")
        exit(1)

        if fd in recvList:
            fd.close()

    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        print("\nINFO: KeyboardInterrupt")
        print("* Closing all sockets and exiting chat server... Goodbye! *")
        clientSocket.close()
        exit(0)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Answer (score 0):

You didn't decode the received bytes

```
rcvdStr = rcvdStr + fd.recv(1024).decode()
```

I haven't exactly checked, so tell me if this helps

**EDIT:**

1. Ok so for starters remove the while statement in line 17 of the client, once the client is connected to the server you can't connect again (make sure you remove the break in the new line 26)
2. The new line 34 is causinf errors (`readyRecvList, readySendList, readyErrList = select.select(recvList, [], [])`)

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\User\Desktop\Client.py", line 93, in <module>
    main()
  File "C:\Users\User\Desktop\Client.py", line 34, in main
    readyRecvList, readySendList, readyErrList = select.select(recvList, [], [])
io.UnsupportedOperation: fileno
```

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Ryan\Desktop\testproj-server.py", line 142, in <module>
    handleConnectedSocket()
  File "C:\Users\Ryan\Desktop\testproj-server.py", line 73, in handleConnectedSocket
    del clientMessages[fd]  # Delete connection information
KeyError: <socket.socket fd=420, family=AddressFamily.AF_INET, type=SocketKind.SOCK_STREAM, proto=0, laddr=('127.0.0.1', 22222), raddr=('127.0.0.1', 51466)>